# Is it normal for a pregnant cat to have a hard stomach?

Tags: cats, behavior, health, breeding

My cat is almost due to delivery. We expect her to give delivery withen these days. Her tummy on each side (where I assume there is a kitten on each) is hard, is this normal?

Also the cat sets on bags in the middle of the hallway and takes the peeing possesion (legs seperated, tail up, moves her legs at first as if digging with them and then settles as if she is ready to pee) can I assume she is trying to give birth in the middle of the hallway? We have company living with us and she is not on good terms with them, can it be that she is a little stupid or doesn't have intuition enough to tell her that she should give birth in a hiding place?

We already provided her with two hiding places (which we can really reach her but never did so she thinks it's a hiding place) she was sitting in one of them the day before. Can it be that she likes the hidings but does not know she should hide once she's due to giving birth?

Comment: it is best if you call a vet about this as a vet know what questions to ask you to get the information he or she need to guide you and tell you what to do.a cat do normaly find a hiding place days before giving birth.

Comment: I know it's best ofcourse, but I'm not asking here just for someone to state the obvious. If someone can answer me then it's great, if not I'll have to get her to the vet soon.

Comment: it is normal that the stomach gets hard,those kittens grow fast in the belly of your cat so it is the same as in pregnant human women the belly gets harder.my comment was more about if the cat is in labour(you ask more than one question here but this is ok)and please post a picture of the kittens when it is possible for you to do so.